# "Race like" condition with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a process that triggers a number of requests that in turn trigger off a number of webhooks. I know the process is complete when I've received all of my webhooks. My model looks something like this.

```
{
    name: 'name',
    status: 'PENDING',
    children: [{
        name: 'child1',
        status: 'PENDING'
    }, {
        name: 'child2',
        status: 'PENDING'
    }]

}
```

The idea is as the webhooks come in, I update the subdoc to `COMPLETE`. At the end of each update I check if the others are complete and if they are, I set `status='COMPLETE'` on the parent. It looks like one invocation of the service is marking it as `COMPLETE` after another invocation has determined it was still `PENDING` but before that second invocation has saved. When the second one saves, it overwrites `COMPLETE` with `PENDING` on the parent.

Here is the code from my schema:

```
methods: {
    doUpdate: function(data) {
        var child = this.children.id(data.childId);
        child.status = 'COMPLETE';
        if (_.every(this.children.status, 'COMPLETE'))
            this.status = 'COMPLETE';
        return this.save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to first find and update the status in one operation, using a variant of mongo's `findAndModify` method, and then check if the other children have completed. I was trying to do two updates in one operation. By breaking it up into two steps, I know that when I check the statuses of the other children, all other invocations will have the most recent state of the document and not get a false reading while another invocation is waiting for `save()` to complete.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can solve your issue when you just modify and save your child objects instead of saving / overwriting the whole document each time.
To do that you can use the [positional $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#update-documents-in-an-array) in your update statement.
Essentially it would look something like this:

```
db.yourChildrenCollection.update(
   { _id: this._id, 'children.name': childName },
   { $set: { 'children.$.status' : 'COMPLETE' } }
)
```

You have to modify the variable names as I do not know your collection name etc. but I think you get the point.